# Remove DevExpress WPF Themes

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I've made use of a devexpress lookupedit control in a project that I'm currently working on, however this is the only devexpress control in use in the project. As such it looks quite out of place compared to the native WPF controls in use. Is there anyway to remove the theming on the control so that it looks like a native combobox or has someone produced a theme that does this that anyone is aware of?

In case anyone suggests, I don't want to replace all the controls in my app for devexpress equivalents because in my experience devexpress controls are generally quite bloated and have a fair amount of overhead.

Thanks.

EDIT ::

I want the devexpress combobox to look like the native combobox, not worried about the contents of the popup template.

[image: First combobox is what I'd like both to look like.]

Comment: Are you using a PopupContentTemplate for your LookUpEdit?

Comment: If so, what control are you using? If you want to remove the theme you will have to edit the actual ControlTemplate of the control. This is the only way.

Comment: I'm not really concerned about the contents of the popuptemplate, just the actual lookup edit, as above.

Comment: This is the thing. I had the same problems with the DxGrid and the editors. You will have to edit the ControlTemplate. Let me post a answer and then we take it from there. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do this is to actually get the style for the `LookUpEdit` and edit the style as you see fit.

First you need to add the ThemeKey reference:

```
xmlns:dxgt="clr-namespace:DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.Themes;assembly=DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.v11.1"
```

Just replace the "v11.1" with your DX version.

Next is the `ControlTemplate`:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="{dxgt:LookUpEditThemeKey ResourceKey=...EnterResourceKey...}" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}"/>
```

Just replace the "...EnterResourceKey..." with the correct key.

Answer (score 2):

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1" dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="None" 
            Width="120" Height="23"/>
```

this post is useful to U

Comment: I've tried this. It doesn't work for me. The [online DevExpress documentation](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#wpf/CustomDocument7407) also mentions this approach, but the `None` theme doesn't remove the theme.